# Format MODIS HDF to Geotiff in MRT

Tags: geotiff-tiff, modis

Am using Modis Reprojection Tool (ModisTool) on MODIS LST data (MOD11A1) to
convert to GeoTiff format.

When I run it I get this error message:

```
Error: OpenGeoTIFFFILE: Opening Output Image File
Unable to open C:\(directory)\ ..LST_Day_1km.tif: Cannot open.
```

What is the correct syntax to use? Is there some way to debug this error?

Comment: Add the command you're calling to be able to help.

Comment: yes, it is because of the space in the path. much obliged!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into the same problem, and somehow figured out the solution (in my case, at least): Make sure that there are no spaces in the path or name of your new file. For some reason, the MRT changes them to underscores instead of using quotes or whatever to keep them as spaces.

As I said, this worked for me (MRT 4.1, Mac OS X 10.8.2).

Comment: Maybe interesting, also in terms of the application of the QA map: http://pymodis.fem-environment.eu/ , a python library to work with MODIS data.